# Apply on DOM event with event parameter

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

Here the case: I want to call the event with apply method, since it's look the one with the best compatibility with any browser.

```
my_object["onchange"].apply(my_object, event)
```

So, the event parameter doesn't exist when you define online, example :

```
<select id="my_select" onchange="my_onchange(event);" >
```

The event object is create by the engine, but what if I call it with apply?

If I try `my_object["onchange"].apply(my_object)` the event parameter is not build. Normal because it's call like a function.

So any idea to do build the event?

update

I have try

```
var event = new Event("onchange", {target:my_object});
```

It's look like target still readonly even with constructor.

Comment: If you use jQuery you can use `$(my_object).trigger("change")`, and it will create an `Event` object. I'm not sure what the equivalent is with plain JS.

Comment: Did you dispatched the event after creation ?

Comment: the apply method call the event as a function.
In fact,  the onchange event is the built in event. 
And apply is used to fire the event. Since  FireEvent is non standard

Answer (score 0):

So my workaround is

var event =  document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
event.initEvent("change", false, true);

my_object.dispatchEvent(event);

it's look like it's compatible with all browser and generate the good event parameter.

Thanks